# how to keep the date unchanged when changing other data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to update the status column in my table, but the date column of the message is also updated. How can I only update the status column only without the date field ?

Data type:

```
Status => Varchar
messgae_date => Timestamp
```

Query :

```
"UPDATE mytable SET status='1' WHERE status='0'"
```

Thank's before ..

Comment: you sure you don't have a trigger happening? what you posted won't do that.

Comment: I dont use trigger

Comment: @Aditya - `mytable` has an `update` trigger or not ?

Comment: I'm not.

I not use trigger

Comment: I think the attributes and innate data types in phpmyadmin affect..

Comment: If the date is being changed, but you are not making that change, then it is either a default value (at create) or a trigger (on update). Are you the only person coding in that database? How do you  know there are no triggers? Have you tried `show triggers` on that table at all?

Comment: Try this and see what is happening : UPDATE mytable SET status='1', message_date=message_date WHERE status='0'

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your question and post the entire DDL statement for creating the table. I believe it will become apparent.

Your post said that message_date is a timestamp. That's a special datatype in MySql and MariaDb that can autoupdate itself at insert or whenever any other data in a row is changed.

> An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current
>   timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed
>   from its current value. An auto-updated column remains unchanged if
>   all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent an
>   auto-updated column from updating when other columns change,
>   explicitly set it to its current value. To update an auto-updated
>   column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the
>   value it should have (for example, set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

Again, please post the table DDL statement. The message_date column will probably look something like this.

```
`message_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```